# Running terraform init in a directory that only contains a tfvars file that references a git source

Tags: terraform, hcl

I am trying to use terraform in a way that was described at the end of the Terraform Up and Running book. The pattern described says that you can have a repo that defines your live environments by using `*.tfvars` files for each environment (such as prod, dev, ad-hoc developer environments, etc.) These `*.tfvars` files reference modules in another repo like this:

```
source = "git::https://github.com/github-user/my-module.git?ref=v0.0.1"

# required variables for `my-module` defined here
foo="bar"
```

This pattern makes a lot of sense to me, it is DRY an
d also makes it easy to compare configuration differences between environments.

When I try to run `terraform init` in a directory that contains a file called `terraform.tfvars` with a reference to my remote module, I get errors. Here's my `terraform.tfvars` file:

```
source = "git::https://github.com/briancaffey/terraform-aws-django.git?ref=v0.0.2"

region="us-east-1"
...
```

Here's the error that I get when I run `terraform init` or `terraform init -var-file terraform.tfvars` or if I specify `-backend-config` values for my s3 backend:

```
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.
```

I had a hard time finding examples that show this pattern, and I also couldn't find anything in the terraform documentation that shows how to use `source` in a `*.tfvars` file.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I'm not sure if this complicates things, but the remote terraform module that I am trying to reference is also published to the official terraform registry: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/briancaffey/django/aws/latest.

Comment: I added this question with some more details to the Terraform section of the Hashicorp discourse board: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/help-with-developing-and-using-a-terraform-module-i-published-to-the-terraform-registry/36789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.tfvars` file is *only* for providing values for input variables of the root modules. The name `source` has no special meaning in that context, and if initialization had succeeded (if your directory had at least one `.tf` file in it) then subsequent operations on this configuration would've reported that there is no variable in your root module named `source`. (An indeed, there cannot be because `source` is a reserved variable name.)

If your goal is to just directly use an external module with a particular set of input variables then the most minimal configuration structure for that is a directory containing a single `.tf` file (any name will do) with the following content:

```
module "main" {
  source = "git::https://github.com/briancaffey/terraform-aws-django.git?ref=v0.0.2"

  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

This specifies both the location of the module and the input variables to pass to it. You can then use this directory with the workflow I think you were intending:

- `terraform init` to initialize the directory, which includes downloading the module source code into a local directory so that subsequent commands can refer to it.
- `terraform apply` to apply the resulting configuration.

This minimal configuration doesn't define any input variables in its own root module, so you won't need any `.tfvars` files or other files to work with it. However, when you run `terraform init` Terraform will itself generate a `.terraform.lock.hcl` file recording the provider version selections, and so if you intend to keep this configuration under version control then you should include that generated file along with your hand-written `.tf` file in order to record those version selections for future use.

Comment: OK, the book refers to a source value in a tfvars files as a "special parameter", but I couldn't find anything about the `source` parameter in the terraform docs. I was thinking that this would use a module as the root configuration, if that makes sense. Maybe the book is referencing an older feature/functionality?

Comment: The [Calling a Child Module](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/syntax#calling-a-child-module) docs don't have a special word for it but they do mention `source` and `version` explicitly as having a different meaning, and state that "most other arguments" are input variables. Only the subset of them that are input variables can appear in a `.tfvars` file.

Comment: There's no equivalent of `source` for the root module, because the root module is always implied to be the module defined in the current working directory. In other words, it's as if the root module were declared with `source = "./"` where `.` means the current directory. (Though in practice you shouldn't actually do that in a real `module` block, because you'll make the root module just call itself recursively, which won't work!)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Originally I wanted to define a single environment with one .tfvars file per environment. But now, as I understand it, I need to define a .tf file that includes this module, specifying the source and version. I'll also need to get the values from the .tfvars file, so won't I need to define another variables.tf file that has the same content of the variables.tf in the module I'm trying to use. Same with the outputs, I need to access some of the module ouputs in my deployment pipeline after terraform apply.

Comment: FYI I added a discussion about this to the terraform community discourse board https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/help-with-developing-and-using-a-terraform-module-i-published-to-the-terraform-registry/36789

Comment: You don't need any `.tfvars` file because all of the values you would've set inside the `.tfvars` file will be inside the `module` block instead, like I showed in my example.